# How do I get my column chart to render without crowding in my shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I have a Shiny app that is rendering a crowded column chart
[image]

How do I allow enable vertical scrolling down the chart to see all bars and labels? I have 7000 labels. My code for generating the graph is below:

```
plot_cost <- function(){
        segments <- segment_data %>% 
            filter(District %in% input$district) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Segments, Improvement_Cost), y = Improvement_Cost, fill = Segments)) +
            geom_col() +
            #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)) +
            coord_flip()
```

My code for rendering it in shiny is below:

```
tabPanel('Graph', icon = icon("fas fa-chart-bar"),
                         
                         plotlyOutput('costs', height = "100%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that:

```
div(
  style = "overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;",
  plotlyOutput('costs', height = "1000px")
)
```